# Fill in trailing variables based on row position using rollmean

Tags: r, loops, apply, zoo

I'm wondering if there is a way to adjust how the `rollmean` function from the `zoo` package handles trailing variables (or possibly another cumulative-type rolling mean function). Say that I have the following data.frame:

```
df <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(sample(1:10), ncol = 3))
df$roll <- rollmean(df$V1, 5, fill = NA, align = "right")
df

   V1  roll
1   2   NA
2   7   NA
3   6   NA
4   1   NA
5   9  5.0
6   5  5.6
7  10  6.2
8   3  5.6
9   4  6.2
10  8  6.0
```

I know that I can use something like `fill = "extend"` with `rollmean` to get the average of all trailing variables, but is there a way to adjust this extend approach so that each trailing variable is cumulative based on the row position? So what I want is something like the below df, where row 4 of `df$roll` has a 4-row rolling window, row 3 has a 3-row rolling window, and so on.

```
   V1  roll
1   2   NA
2   7  4.5
3   6  5.0
4   1  4.0
5   9  5.0
6   5  5.6
7  10  6.2
8   3  5.6
9   4  6.2
10  8  6.0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rollapply` (and `rollapplyr` which defaults to right alignment) support the `partial = TRUE` argument.  See `?rollapply`

```
transform(df, roll = rollapplyr(V2, 5, mean, partial = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
   V1 V2 roll
1   1  2  2.0
2   2  7  4.5
3   3  6  5.0
4   4  1  4.0
5   5  9  5.0
6   6  5  5.6
7   7 10  6.2
8   8  3  5.6
9   9  4  6.2
10 10  8  6.0
```

**Note:** To make the code for producing the input reproducible one would have to use `set.seed(...)`.  Since that is not done we used this:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = 1:10, V2 = c(2L, 7L, 6L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 10L, 
3L, 4L, 8L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have used `sample()` in the original question, but this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much.

Comment: Also, for my actual purpose, I was able to throw the `rollapplyr(V2, 5, mean, partial = TRUE))` line into the `dplyr` chain I am working in, which worked perfectly.